# Why does apt-get consume stdin when it installs something but not otherwise?

Tags: shell, terminal, command, command-line-interface, buffer

I am connected to a remote Debian system via macOS Terminal.

#### Command after `apt-get` never runs if `apt-get` installs something

At first, I copy these three commands from a text file on my macOS and paste it into the terminal with a single <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> press:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove tree
sudo apt-get -y install tree
echo hi
```

Here is what I see in the Terminal.

```
lone@lone:~$ sudo apt-get -y remove tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'tree' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
lone@lone:~$ sudo apt-get -y install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
(Reading database ... 31853 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tree_1.7.0-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tree (1.7.0-5) ...
Setting up tree (1.7.0-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
lone@lone:~$
```

The third command, `echo hi`, was never executed. Why?

#### Command after `apt-get` does run if `apt-get` does not install anything

Next time, I simply paste these two commands with a single <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> press:

```
sudo apt-get -y install tree
echo hi
```

This time, since `tree` is already installed, `apt-get` does not need to install it again. This is the output I see:

```
lone@lone:~$ sudo apt-get -y install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tree is already the newest version (1.7.0-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
lone@lone:~$ echo hi
hi
```

This time `echo hi` was executed. Why?

Both results are reproducible every time I perform these two sets of operations. Why does the `echo hi` command not run in the first example but does in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` or a program called by `apt-get` is emptying its stdin (which happens to be the same as the shell's, where your list of commands originates).

Since you know nothing needs to be to read from the user, redirect stdin from /dev/null:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove tree </dev/null
sudo apt-get -y install tree </dev/null
echo hi
```

Comment: Why does `apt-get` not empty the stdin in the second case when there is nothing to install?

Comment: Because in your second example it didn't hit a code path that emptied stdin and it didn't call a program which hit a code path that emptied stdin. From a cursory look at the apt-get source, it's more likely that a called program is the culprit. A lot of programs can get called during an install.

Answer (score 0):

Append `-o=DPkg::FlushSTDIN=0` to your `apt-get install` command.

Ref: [Source Code](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/766b24b7f7484751950c76bc66d3d6cdeaf949a5/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc#L2007-L2022)